# What does "to be a fixture" mean?

Tags: metaphors

In Arthur Conan Doyle's "The Hound of Baskervilles" I've run into an idiom I still cannot quite wrap my head around. In the course of a discussion with Dr. Watson, Sherlock Holmes says:

> There is a delightful freshness about you, Watson, which makes it a pleasure to exercise  any small powers which I possess at
>   your expense. A gentleman goes forth on a showery and miry day. He
>   returns immaculate in the evening with the gloss still on his hat and
>   his boots. *He has been a **fixture** therefore all day.*

According to the dictionary, a fixture is

- something (such as a light, toilet, sink, etc.) that is attached to a house or building and that is not removed when the house or building is sold
- a person or thing that has been part of something or involved in something for a long time

None of the above makes any sense in the context to me, so what is the meaning of that last phrase?

Update: stirred in the right direction by Ricky, I understood that the author employed the word *fixture* metaphorically, associating Watson with a house fixture, thus exaggerating the fact that Watson hasn't moved from the only place he'd been on that day.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you that the word *fixture* means? And don't look in the Old English dictionary, either: this isn’t *Beowulf* for God’s sake. It’s from only a few years ago.

Comment: Tchrist, stop making stack exchange a worse place.

Comment: Throughout the entire Stack Exchange, we expect you to do your own research before asking. Notice that the tool tip on the downvote button says ***"This question does not show any research effort."***  That should tell you something. If you can't bother to look things up in a dictionary, then this is not the site for you because that part is your job, not ours.

Comment: What makes your think I have not done my own research? Let me help your myopia out and bring it to your attention that the word, as it is defined in the dictionary, namely as an attachment to a house, is not suitable for direct interpretation. The phrase employs a figure of speech. A metaphor, which I was not able to grasp at first. Do some useful moderation. You're overqualified(?) For this.

Comment: You have to **show us your research.** You didn't. That's what the close reason says. And clearly you looked in a cheap and underpowered dictionary, given that [mine says: *4. A person or thing permanently confined to or established in a particular place or position.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/70840?redirectedFrom=fixture#eid) We can't be forever looking up words people don't understand for them. They have to show us why they couldn't make sense of basic reference material, which means you have to show it to us. You didn't. Close reason stands.

Comment: @Slavic It may help to note the red-diamond and the majestic "us".

Comment: @Kris, it may help in what regard?

Comment: Could someone please add a bit more plot context. Do we know where it was that Watson had been all day? There seems to be an assumption, or knowledge, that it was a pub.

Comment: "You have been at your club all day", said Sherlock earlier. So it's a club, not a bar, although I'm not aware what club Watson attended at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that he (Dr. Watson in this case) had not stirred from whatever spot he was standing/sitting on all day. Always in the same place. Never venturing outside. *Fixed*, as it were.

Comment: It makes sense now. I was more inclined to believe it was an idiom but it is instead a metaphor.

Comment: Please don't answer General Reference questions that should be placed On Hold until and unless fixed.

Comment: @tchrist Okay. Can I edit them, though?

Comment: Of course. The site needs more editors. I would be completely delighted if every post were copyedited to meet site standards.

Comment: @tchrist: As would I. But very few of the posts I have looked at over the past two months or so could be said to meet any kind of standards, and the vast majority of them belong in the Learners forum rather than here. I don't see anyone willing to do anything about that. Which is why I pounced on this one (as I earlier pounced on some others) as one that at least makes sense, is perfectly clear, and comes off as legitimate, however general it may be.

Comment: All these things are a real and perennial problem. But "jess gimme da codez" is hardly unique to our site. Unfortunately.

Comment: @tchrist: I agree. Which is why I think (erroneously, perhaps) that we must try not to alienate folks who read (and quote) good books and sincerely wish to learn.

Comment: Very well: I agree with that.

Comment: Yep, it's a fixture like a light fixture or plumbing fixture.  Something that doesn't move, and, in a bar or such, implies that the person could well be a statue or such, since they are always there.

Comment: Except neither lighting nor plumbing fixtures were common enough at the time of this writing for that to be the analogy. Instead, the fixtures most in the minds of residential tenants would have been door garden items such as roses, holly hedges, or orchard trees; or perhaps window glass and chimney improvements. This is the legal definition of fixture vis a vis the tenant -  freeholder contract. Commercial fixtures were production equipment such as stills and mills and other equipment structurally tied to the earth or other buildings.

Comment: relevant definition and explanation [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=f24sAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA5&dq=%22fixture%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9jrL8453dAhUCKKwKHV_SBlEQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22fixture%22&f=false) from 1836 law book.

Comment: @PhilSweet some pieces of shop, library and bar furniture would have been regarded as "fixtures" in the sense of "fixtures and fittings" in the late 19th century. I think particularly of bar backs with shelves and a mirror and the complex sets of drawers found in old chemists shops. If Watson had ensconsed himself in a pub, cafe or library with a view of the suspect's house he might have become a "fixture" for the day.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, those are all good examples. My point was that you didn't go into a store and by a bathroom fixture or lighting fixture in 1900. That usage didn't come about until 1920s in the US. Prior to that, things didn't become fixtures until they were permanently installed. So the metaphor has suffered from the shifting sands of time in that the image of Watson-as-a-fixture is different now than in 1902.